# React route path not working in browser url. Is there any fix on react 18v?

Tags: reactjs

Below route path "/Campaign/test" not working browser url (React 18v). when i use "/Campaign" only, then it will work fine.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/Campaign/test" element={<Home/>}/>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Please help me
i need path like this **http://localhost:3000/Campaign/test**
[image]

Comment: You can try adding exact prop to the route

Comment: exact prop used. but not working

Comment: have you tried using nested routes?